# How to update java object from fields and values provided in Map

Tags: java

I need to update a document in MongoDB. This document has many fields, and I want to avoid taking entire document from User.  Basically user should only provide Map (key-val, where key is field name and value is respective value)
I tried Update from Spring Data, but it was removing other fields.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
To solve this,

- Retrieve Document from MongoDB and map it as Model
- Take `Map<String,Object>` from user
  and push updates

```java
public boolean updateObjectAttributes(SomeModel someModel, Map<String, Object> list) throws Exception { 

    if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : list.entrySet()) {
            Field f = SomeModel.class.getDeclaredField(entry.getKey());
            f.setAccessible(true);
            f.set(someModel , entry.getValue());
        }
    }
    //... Further validations followed by mongo update
}
```